# Dowloading Java jdk on linux

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to download java jdk and when I try to extract the file I get this message

```
tar (child): jdk-8u241-linux-i586.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have it downloaded and the file is on my desktop and this is what i entered

```
root@faiq-desktop:~/Desktop# tar zxvf jdk-8u241-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

Comment: What command did you type? Were you in the correct working directory?

Comment: Your filename is wrong. Do ls first and see the exact file name, the use it. Hint: copy and paste helps.

Comment: do a `ls` and ensure that the file is actually there

Comment: @FaiqFaizy Type the command `ls` and see what it says.

Comment: it says no such file but I can see it on my Desktop

Comment: This question is more about basic Linux usage than programming. Would https://unix.stackexchange.com/ be a more appropriate venue?

Comment: oh ok I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are facing this because you are not in that directory, first you need to cd into that directory.

```
tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz   # Replace the filename with your's
```

referenced from: [“Cannot open: No such file or directory” when extracting a tar file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486264/cannot-open-no-such-file-or-directory-when-extracting-a-tar-file)

Comment: @gunjan it is not in good taste to explicitly request acceptance and upvotes. Good answers will get them automatically